# PHP Warning: array_shift() expects parameter1 to be array, null given in /.../.../twitter_user_timeline/view.php

Tags: php

Although this error has appeared on Stack Overflow below, the answers do not solve my problem.

> PHP Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/vhosts/my.domain/httpdocs/blocks/twitter_user_timeline/view.php on line 2

I understand I am passing null in the array, which I guess is wrong; how do I solve this?

This is the aforementioned line 2 in the named PHP file:

```
<?php 
   $tweet = array_shift( $this->controller->getTweets() ) ;
?>
```

This is the controller file (in case it is relevant to the above):

```
<?php
defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");

require_once(__DIR__ . '/twitter_api.php');

class TwitterUserTimelineBlockController extends BlockController {
protected $btTable           = 'btTwitterUserTimeline';
protected $btWrapperClass    = 'ccm-ui';
protected $btInterfaceWidth  = 480;
protected $btInterfaceHeight = 360;

public function getBlockTypeDescription() {
    return t("get Latest Tweet");
}

public function getBlockTypeName() {
    return t("Twitter User Timeline");
}

public function getTweets(){
    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token'        => "blah,blah,blah",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "blah,blah,blah",
        'consumer_key'              => "blah,blah,blah",
        'consumer_secret'           => "blah,blah,blah",
    );

    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    return json_decode( $twitter->setGetfield("?                    screen_name=domain_uk&count=1")
            ->buildOauth ('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json', 'GET')
            ->performRequest(), true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Parameter for array_shift() should be array, $this->controller->getTweets() check the response of this method i think it is getting null

Comment: `$this->controller->getTweets()` is `NULL` (and not an array) because `json_decode()` cannot parse the string returned by `$twitter->setGetField(...)->buildOauth(...)->performRequest()`. Put the value returned by `performRequest()` on screen and see why it cannot be decoded (because it is not a JSON, in the first place).

Comment: Thanks for swift response axiac.. unfortunately i'm only learning this stuff. When you say put the value returned on screen, what exactly do you mean? so sorry...

Comment: Hey P_Moz, were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Hey domdom - unfortunately not. this is still an issue for me. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The answer really lies within the error message:

> PHP Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, **null given**

It is therefore clear that in this line:

```
$tweet = array_shift($this->controller->getTweets());
```

`$this->controller->getTweets()` can (and at least sometimes does) return `null`. Now, you could go ahead and put a band-aid around that real quick by making sure `array_shift()` will not be used if `getTweets()` did not return an array, as desired:

```
$tweets = $this->controller->getTweets(); // This might be null
$tweet = $tweets ? array_shift($tweets) : null;
```

Note, however, that now `$tweet` might be `null`, which you need to handle appropriately. Obviously, it would be better to not use a band-aid here but to check why `getTweets()` (sometimes) returns `null` and fix that - unless that is indeed intended behavior. We can't tell as we don't know the contract for that method (i.e. how you want that method to work).